# Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' Position: 22

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, spring-security

I'm trying to make my first defense. But I immediately encountered an error. I have created all the tables and fields in the database, so the error is not related to a typo of the names.

Method in configure

```
        @Bean
    public JdbcUserDetailsManager users(DataSource dataSource) {
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
                .username("user")
                .password("{bcrypt}$2y$12$0./a1TvfPwxj.OTlQLF1HONCpHXHtrcrn7CR5sPE7UHSWLbkPjxZG")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        UserDetails admin = User.builder()
                .username("admin")
                .password("{bcrypt}$2y$12$0./a1TvfPwxj.OTlQLF1HONCpHXHtrcrn7CR5sPE7UHSWLbkPjxZG")
                .roles("ADMIN", "USER")
                .build();
        JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
        if (jdbcUserDetailsManager.userExists(user.getUsername())) {
            jdbcUserDetailsManager.deleteUser(user.getUsername());
        }
        if (jdbcUserDetailsManager.userExists(admin.getUsername())) {
            jdbcUserDetailsManager.deleteUser(admin.getUsername());
        }
        jdbcUserDetailsManager.createUser(user);
        jdbcUserDetailsManager.createUser(admin);
        return jdbcUserDetailsManager;
    }
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'users' defined in class path resource [com/example/vkr2/configs/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager]: Factory method 'users' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select username from users where username = ?]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: The "users" relation does not exist


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'users' defined in class path resource [com/example/vkr2/configs/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager]: Factory method 'users' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select username from users where username = ?]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: The "users" relation does not exist


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'users' defined in class path resource [com/example/vkr2/configs/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager]: Factory method 'users' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select username from users where username = ?]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: The "users" relation does not exist
```

application.yaml

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=security
    username: postgres
    password: 12345
```

One of the features is the red highlighting in the org.springframework.boot plugin

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>vkr2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>vkr2</name>
    <description>vkr2</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Please add your pom.xml and application.properties/yml.

Comment: What happens if you execute the following from the posgres client: SELECT * from "security"."users"; while being connected to localhost:5432 as user 'postgres'?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like trouble with your passwords. Try it like this

```
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
...
UserDetails user = User.withUsername("myusername")
  .password(passwordEncoder.encode("mypassword"))
  .roles("ROLE_USER")
  .build();
```

Introduction to Spring Security with users and roles is here:
https://agile-coding.blogspot.com/2022/09/spring-security-roles.html